# How to iterate item with next item in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, data-structures

I want to filter my each item of list and know what is the next item as well. I have few condition to check. I have data coming from the server

```
data class BollywoodMovie(
    val year: String? = null,
    val movieList: List<NewMovieItem>? = null
)

data class NewMovieItem(
    val name: String? = null,
    val type: String? = null,
    val isReleaseNow: Boolean? = null,
    val screenNumber: String? = null
)
```

Filter out into new **data class**

```
data class FilterMovieItem(
    val name: String,
    val type: String,
    val isReleasedInThreader: Boolean
)
```

I tried this piece of code

```
fun main() {
    val movieList = listOf(
        NewMovieItem("Kisi Ka Bhai Kisi Ki Jaan", "action", true, "Screen 1"),
        NewMovieItem("Pathaan", "action", true, ""),
        NewMovieItem("Tu Jhoothi Main Makkaar", "romance"),
        NewMovieItem("r", "", true, "Screen 3"),
        NewMovieItem("Dasara", "romance", false, "Screen 1"),
        NewMovieItem("Kuttey", "comedy", false, "Screen 2"),
        NewMovieItem("Selfiee", "comedy", true, "Screen 3"),
        NewMovieItem("Selfiee", "other", false, "Screen 1"),
    )
    val unfilteredList = BollywoodMovie("2023", movieList)
    val unFilteredMovieList = unfilteredList.movieList.orEmpty()
    val (filterList, otherMovieItem) = filterData(unFilteredMovieList)
    println(filterList)
    println(otherMovieItem)
}

private fun filterData(unFilteredMovieList: List<NewMovieItem>): Pair<List<FilterMovieItem>, MutableList<FilterMovieItem>> {
    val otherMovieItem = mutableListOf<FilterMovieItem>()
    val filterList = unFilteredMovieList
        .asSequence()
        .mapNotNull { currentItem ->
            // I want nextItem as well to check some conditions
            if (!currentItem.name.isNullOrEmpty() && !currentItem.type.isNullOrEmpty() && currentItem.isReleaseNow != null) {
                FilterMovieItem(currentItem.name, currentItem.type, currentItem.isReleaseNow)
            } else {
                null
            }
        }
        .map { filterMovieItem ->
            if (filterMovieItem.type == "other") {
                println("Movie is other Type")
                otherMovieItem.add(filterMovieItem)
            }
            filterMovieItem
        }.toList()
    return Pair(filterList, otherMovieItem)
}
```

I don't understand what is the correct way to iterate current item with next item and make condition on that basis. Above logic is only work for single iteration. My main goal is to when I am checking on this code

```
if (!item.name.isNullOrEmpty() && !item.type.isNullOrEmpty() && item.isReleaseNow != null) {
```

then I want to next item value as well and make some condition. So can you guys guide me what is the idiomatic way of doing this in kotlin?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's `zipWithNext`, but then the last item in the list will not be iterated in first position, since it has no next item to check.

```
val filterList = unFilteredMovieList
    .zipWithNext()
    .mapNotNull { (currentItem, nextItem) -> // destructuring a Pair here
        // ...
    }
```

If you need to include the last item in iteration, you can use `chunked(2)` and check if the next item is available.

```
val filterList = unFilteredMovieList
    .chunked(2)
    .mapNotNull { list -> 
        val currentItem = list[0]
        if (list.size < 2) {
            // we are on last item
            // ...
        } else {
            val nextItem = list[1]
            // ...
        }
    }
```

By the way, your use of `map` could be simplified by using `onEach` instead or `.also` and `filterTo`. Your unnecessary use of `asSequence` is probably hurting performance slightly.

Comment: Hi @Tenfour thanks for guidance to use `zipWithNext()`. In first option you used `.forEach` how would I create `FilterMovieItem`?

Comment: I am confused because my code `mapNotNull` is return type of `FilterMovieItem` and you code with `forEach` is nothing. Sorry but I didn't understand.

Comment: In your second option how will you print `currentItem` and `nextItem` without declaring the variable?

Comment: In second option if we have odd number list then it will give you an error i.e. `val list = (1..11).toList()`

Comment: Sorry, I had a mistake in my second example. I have updated both examples to be more like your code.